# How to use expectationForPredicate with a XCUIElementQuery UISwitch

Tags: uiswitch, xctestcase

How to write a UI Test (XCTestCase) that waits for a UISwitch to be enabled.

I added this code to one of my tests but it timed out:

```
let firstSwitch = XCUIApplication().switches.elementBoundByIndex(0)
_ = self.expectationForPredicate(
  NSPredicate(format: "self.value = %@", enabled),
  evaluatedWithObject: firstSwitch,
  handler: nil)
self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(15.0, handler: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `self.value` with `self.value.boolValue`:

```
let firstSwitch = XCUIApplication().switches.elementBoundByIndex(0)
_ = self.expectationForPredicate(
  NSPredicate(format: "self.value.boolValue = %@", enabled),
  evaluatedWithObject: firstSwitch,
  handler: nil)
self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(15.0, handler: nil)
```